# I am trying to solve a circular import error,I spent hours in vain

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I get this error:  The included URLconf 'liskerproject.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

liskerproject is the root directory and contains the root "urls.py".
Lisk is another directory that contains "url.py"

This is how my root urls look like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path,include
from users import views as user_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('edit/',user_views.edit,name='edit'),
    path('',include('Lisk.url')),
    path('register/',user_views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='user_templates/login.html'),name='login'),
    path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='user_templates/logout.html'),name='logout')
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is how Lisk.url looks like:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Politics_topic,Questionpolitics,Updatepolitics,Politics_post_details,Deletepoliticspost,Profile,home
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',home,name='home'),
    path('about/',views.about,name = 'about Lisk'),
    path('interests/',views.interests,name='interests'),
    path('profile/',Profile.as_view(template_name='lisk_templates/profile.html'),name = 'profile'),


    path('politics_topic/', Politics_topic.as_view(template_name='lisk_templates/politics_topic_template.html'),
         name='Politics_topic'),
    path('ask_politics/', Questionpolitics.as_view(template_name='lisk_templates/ask_politics_template.html'),
         name='ask_politics'),
    path('politicspost/<int:pk>/',Politics_post_details.as_view(template_name='lisk_templates/politics_post_details.html'),
         name='politics_post_details'),
    path('politicspost/<int:pk>/update/',Updatepolitics.as_view(template_name='lisk_templates/ask_politics_template.html'),
         name='updatepoliticspost'),
    path('politicspost/<int:pk>/delete/',Deletepoliticspost.as_view(template_name='lisk_templates/delete_politics_confirmation.html'),name ='deletepoliticspost')

]
```

This how Lisk.views look like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post, PoliticsPost
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin




def home(request):
    return render(request, 'lisk_templates/home_template.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'lisk_templates/about_template.html')


@login_required
def interests(request):
    return render(request, 'lisk_templates/interests_template.html')


class Profile(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']





#POLITICS-------------
class Politics_topic(ListView):
    model= PoliticsPost
    context_object_name = 'politicsposts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']


class Politics_post_details(DetailView):
    model = PoliticsPost
    context_object_name = 'politicsposts'


class Questionpolitics(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = PoliticsPost
    fields =['question','description']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Politics_topic')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class Updatepolitics(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,UpdateView):
    model = PoliticsPost
    fields = ['question','description']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Politics_topic')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


class Deletepoliticspost(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):

    model = PoliticsPost
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Politics_topic')
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

#POLITICS-------------
```

Comment: Confirm if you used ```url.py``` or ```urls.py```

Comment: @Biplove Lamichhane, I used exactly what I posted.

Comment: it's not that clear, can you give us just the project structure with just `app` names and their `ulrs.py` files ? i guess you have setup your custom project structure like gathering apps with same logic under one folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution guys, it is pretty simple.
I removed

`from .views import Politics_topic,Questionpolitics,Updatepolitics,Politics_post_details,Deletepoliticspost,Profile,home`
In `Lisk.url`

I only used `from . import views` and I called  all the functions in `views,py` with the dot operator.
Don't ask me how it worked, but it did work.